# Azure API management cant access app service api

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I have an Azure app service that is protected by AAD Express Authentication; I intend to use API Management Service to manage it, but when i import the api in the management service and test one of my get function; it says 401 Unauthorized. I have tried adding "validate jwt" policy but I think I am doing something wrong. Can you tell me the correct way of making the connection to the AAD protected app service thru Api management service?

Answer (score 0):

Azure API Management feature allows you to expose apps deployed in Azure App Service to manage, protect, and secure APIs.

To start using Azure API Management, go to the App Service extension, and follow these steps:

1. Select a new or existing API Management service instance for exposing the app.
2. Manage the API—apply policies, edit or download an OpenAPI
   specification file,change the API configuration, or navigate to the
   API Management instance.

Please refer to this [document](https://azure.github.io/api-management-resources/)